# VMWare Workstation 12.x and Mac OSX Capitan: bridged network doen't work

Tags: networking, osx-elcapitan, vmware-workstation

I try to use the mode bridged in VMware workstation. But the Mac OSX Guest doen't get any IP from DHCP. What can I do?